# Cannot get the httpPost params but can get the httpGet from php

Tags: android

Here is my android code to send request:

```
// defaultHttpClient
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(serverUrl);
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("abc", "abc2"));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
InputStream is = null;
is = httpEntity.getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
}
is.close();
String json = "";
json = sb.toString();
Log.d("JSON", "JSON is:" + json);
```

and here is my php code to get the request:

```
<?php

echo $_POST['abc'];

?>
```

When I run the application, the string `json` is nothing. I expect to get `JSON is:abc2`
Then I change the some code, in android part:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(serverUrl);
```

change to:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(serverUrl + "?abc=abc3");
```

in php part:

```
<?php

echo $_GET['abc'];

?>
```

This time, the string `json` in logcat is `JSON is:abc3`. It is correct!!
I have tried lots of time, but seems cannot send HttpPost request with params.
Any one can help me to find out what wrongs with my code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);

DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(serverUrl);

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("abc", "abc2"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    nameValuePairs.clear();
    nameValuePairs = null;

    HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
    response = null;
    Log.e("Server Response",EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity));
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("IOException", " IOException ");
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e){
    Log.e("Exception", " Exception ");
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    httpParameters = null;
    httppost = null;
}
```